# modify remote agent configuration in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I have a newly built vm machine which I am configuring as Bamboo remote agent. I can do it successfully. But the display name in Bamboo shows the agent name in caps (PERF8) whereas I want it as perf8
I did the following:

```
      1. Stop Bamboo service in Agent.
      2. Delete agent in Bamboo
      3. Modify the bamboo-agent.cfg to perf8
      4. Start service
      5. Approve Bamboo service in Agent
```

But it only leaves a duplicate remote agent in Bamboo (PERF8, perf8(2)) instead of modifying the existing one.

Since its a vmware, changing the name in Bamboo Agent Edit details is going to be washed out when I revert the agent. Could someone please help me fix it please?

Comment: I tried the same when the agent was running and its all good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  1. Start Bamboo service in Agent.
  2. Modify the bamboo-agent.cfg to perf8
  4. Stop service
  5. Start Bamboo service in Agent
```